# Common custom menu for a javaFX multi page application. Where should i put it Stage or Scene?

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

We are planning to develop a desktop Application with JavaFX,  the application will have multiple pages. I need a menu to switch between the pages and also some custom menu options.
I'm aware we could undecorate a stage which will disable all the default controls .
My question is , what is a better approach ? 
1. Develop the custom menu on the Stage itself (Is that possible) ? or 
2. create a scene (which acts as a root to all other screens)and add the controls to it.
Please let me know the approaches that I can take?

Answer (score 0):

I had a good result setting my root to a border panel, adding the menu to the top and having the menu actions replace the panel in the center. Other approach could be using a stack panel at the center, adding the other panels to it and pulling the desired panel to the top on a menu action.

Comment: That was the approach I was taking. I refered to the article below.         [link](http://javajdk.net/tutorial/multiple-javafx-scenes-sharing-one-menubar/ )

Comment: I see I reinvented the wheel :)

It seems to be the best approach as the menu needs to be a container's child to show up.

Comment: How do I add control icons (close ,maximize and minimize ) to the menu bar ?

Comment: You cannot add icons to the menu bar. The best is to wrap the border pane with a stack pane and add on top of everything a transparent pane where you can place the buttons. Then you can skin the buttons with css to display images, have different colors, etc.

Comment: Does that mean , I should have a stackpane as parent for the border- pane and try adding the icons to the stackpane ?

Comment: Almost. Try adding the icons to a transparent pane added to the stack pane.

Comment: Never tried this, but could you add the control buttons and the menu bar to, say, an `AnchorPane`, and use the anchor pane as the top node in a border pane?

Comment: I have not experimented with that as I had always decorated windows, it was just an idea. Yours seems also good. Try it and tell me if it works.